# Refind - How to start a batch script when booting on Win10?

Tags: windows-10, batch, multi-boot, refind

I will build my new computer soon, and i'm trying to figure out, how I will configure my boot manager (Refind or Clover).

Example of Multiboot :

1. boot on Windows 10 (no script)
2. boot on Windows 10 and run batch script that start "Steam Big Pictures"

Is it something possible ?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to have two installations of Windows 10?

Comment: Hey Anaksunaman,

It will be just one installation of Windows 10 with 2 entries (with and without script, depending of the entry selected).

Comment: Clover: https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/310038-manually-install-clover-and-configure-boot-priority-with-easyuefi-in-windows/  ReFind: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/